# How can I get detailed gcc and clang version information from the Android NDK?

Tags: gcc, android-ndk

The Android NDK provides both gcc and clang toolchains. I haven't tried out clang yet, but at least with gcc it seems like the version that's shipped with the NDK is a fork and different than mainline gcc releases. I can't find minor release version information for the toolchains (ie, its just gcc-4.8, not gcc-4.8.x)

I'm using lots of C++11 in my code and most C++ compilers have had a fair amount of bugs that get fixed with minor releases. For example I'm using gcc 4.8.2 right now on the desktop and I need to work around a bug with lambda capture and with passing certain flags for threading support.

How do I determine whether or not these bugs exist in the gcc toolchain provided with the NDK? Is this information listed anywhere in the NDK (because the gcc binaries themselves don't seem to have anything useful when you pass -v to them; its just the major release version information)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can study the prebuilt toolchain commits at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/+/master/SOURCES (see https://android.googlesource.com/?format=HTML | grep 4.8 for other versions) and the toolchain tree itself at https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/gcc/+/master/gcc-4.8/

Comment: Seems like a huge chore. I wish they'd tag against the mainline releases